# Self-hosted GitLab Runner with shell executor can’t find npm

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, nvm

I’m configuring a very simple CI job. GitLab Runner is running on my own server, the specific runner for this project has been registered, with the `shell` executor, as I want to simply run shell commands.

```
stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "public/dist/main.js"
  only:
    - master
```

The job fails at the first command, `npm install`, with `npm: command not found`. I just installed `npm` and `node` via `npm`. If I SSH on my server and run `npm -v`, I can see version 8.5.5 is installed. If I `sudo su gitlab-runner`, which I suppose is what GitLab Runner is running as, `npm -v` works just as well.

I installed `npm` while `gitlab-runner` was already running. So I ran `service gitlab-runner restart`, thinking that it had to reevaluate its `PATH`, but it didn’t fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by simply adding this command before `npm install`: `. ~/.bashrc`.

I’m not sure why gitlab-runner didn’t properly read `.bashrc` before, even though I restarted it. Maybe it’s not supposed to? That would be contrary to what’s said in the [GitLab CI runners docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/#shell-profile-loading).

**N.B.:** A key element in me being able to debug this was to clone the repo on a folder on my server, cd into it, and run **`gitlab-runner exec shell build`** after any (local) change to `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Skipping the whole commit + push + wait was a *huge* time (and sanity) saver.